# child list variation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been using jQuery to create a simple child list, however the style of child list I am generating is as thus:

```
parent
 -> child1
 -> child2
 -> childN
```

The style of list I want to generate needs to render like this.

```
parent
 -> child1
  --> child2
   --->childN
```

So that a child is appended a new child node.

Currently I have been utilising jQuery's .last().append() features however they only seem to be able to generate example 1 and for some reason i can not for the life of me work out this very basic problem, should I utilise prepend(), but i feel as though that may not work correctly ?

```
var nodeSets = document.createElement(arrayElems[0]);

for (var i=1; i < arrayElems.length; i++) {
 $(nodeSets).last().append(document.createElement(arrayElems[i]));
}
```

Comment: What does your HTML look like? How are you building your tree????

Comment: something like that Neal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML

```
<div id='target'/>
```

javascript:

```
var elems=[
    '<div>test</div>',
    '<div>test2</div>',
    '<div>test3</div>',
    '<div>test4</div>',
    '<div>test5</div>',
    '<div>test6</div>',
    '<div>test7</div>'
    ];
var lastelem=$('#target');
for (var n in elems) {
    var e=$(elems[n]);
    lastelem.append(e);
    lastelem=e;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BhZtu/1/